# OpenSSL Commutative Encryption isn't behaving as expected

Tags: encryption, cryptography, openssl, aes

I'm currently teaching myself commutative encryption for communication (it's easier if you don't ask why I'm not using SSL.) I'm using openssl as the back end of the encryption. To crunch this data, I'm using `aes-256-ctr` for commutative encryption (thanks to the wonderful people over at Crypto.SE for teaching me about that.) Here's what I'm doing:

```
echo -n lemons|openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -nosalt -pass pass:a |openssl enc -aes-256-ctr -nosalt -pass pass:b |openssl enc -d -aes-256-ctr -nosalt -pass pass:a |openssl enc -d -aes-256-ctr -nosalt -pass pass:b
```

This works quite well. But I need this on one line, base64 encoded. So I add `-a -A` to the each OpenSSL command and it returns nothing. Weird. I'm sure im over looking something, or there's a big misunderstanding between how I think it should work and how it actually does. I considered going back to Crypto.SE to ask this but seeing how this has more to do with the OpenSSL command rather than the cryptography behind it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that scripting is the right way to perform commutative encryption though.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. Is the php library good for this? That's what its going to be implemented in.

Comment: I'll reverse that, if PHP is your language, then mcrypt seems to have CTR functionality build in. But make sure with scripting languages in general that the input to the encryption/decryption functions is as expected, e.g. by printing out all the I/O values in hex. Mcrypt for PHP also happily accepts incorrect key and IV sizes. Be aware that the underlying mcrypt libraries are *unmaintained* for several years already.